# OCR character accuracy measuring test methodology

Tags: c++, algorithm, ocr

I have a requirement to analyze OCR accuracy of a result processed by an OCR library within an application. According to the context of the application I prefer going with character accuracy measurement instead of words.

Therefore I believe total error count  should be addition of inserted chars, substituted chars and deleted chars in a particular string.Then the accuracy percentage can be calculated against the total number for correct chars in the string.

Could anybody suggest an algorithm or a clue to calculate this Accuracy.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out these links with scientific papers about Accuracy to OCR algorithms.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.42.5435&rep=rep1&type=pdf
http://www.dlib.org/dlib/march09/holley/03holley.html

It's a quite usual you have a confidence rate in OCR algorithms as well. If you check python-tesseract for instance (C++ based) there is a confidence rate by the funcion

Python:

```
`api.MeanTextConf()`
```

C++:

```
`
Pix *image = pixRead("/usr/src/tesseract-3.02/phototest.tif");
  tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
  api->Init(NULL, "eng");
  api->SetImage(image);
  Boxa* boxes = api->GetComponentImages(tesseract::RIL_TEXTLINE, true, NULL, NULL);
  printf("Found %d textline image components.\n", boxes->n);
  for (int i = 0; i < boxes->n; i++) {
    BOX* box = boxaGetBox(boxes, i, L_CLONE);
    api->SetRectangle(box->x, box->y, box->w, box->h);
    char* ocrResult = api->GetUTF8Text();
    ***//CONFIDENCE RATE
    int conf = api->MeanTextConf();***
    fprintf(stdout, "Box[%d]: x=%d, y=%d, w=%d, h=%d, confidence: %d, text: %s",
                    i, box->x, box->y, box->w, box->h, conf, ocrResult);
  }`
```

That could work for you.

Best wishes